# Horizon Docker Image is exiting as a failure with an "Access to the path is denied" error

Tags: docker, horizon

Trying to setup a vanilla Sitecore XP docker implementation with a Horizon docker image.  Everything runs fine except for the Horizon container.

The error being provided from Docker Desktop is:

````
Unhandled exception. System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Horizon' is denied.

   at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerator`1.CreateDirectoryHandle(String path, Boolean ignoreNotFound)

   at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerator`1.Init()

   at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerator`1..ctor(String directory, Boolean isNormalized, EnumerationOptions options)

   at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerable`1..ctor(String directory, FindTransform transform, EnumerationOptions options, Boolean isNormalized)

   at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerableFactory.FileSystemInfos(String directory, String expression, EnumerationOptions options, Boolean isNormalized)

   at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.InternalEnumerateInfos(String path, String searchPattern, SearchTarget searchTarget, EnumerationOptions options)

   at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFileSystemInfos(String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing.Abstractions.DirectoryInfoWrapper.EnumerateFileSystemInfos()+MoveNext()

   at System.Linq.Enumerable.OfTypeIterator[TResult](IEnumerable source)+MoveNext()

   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing.Internal.MatcherContext.Match(DirectoryInfoBase directory, String parentRelativePath)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing.Internal.MatcherContext.Execute()

   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing.Matcher.Execute(DirectoryInfoBase directoryInfo)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing.MatcherExtensions.GetResultsInFullPath(Matcher matcher, String directoryPath)

   at Sitecore.Framework.Runtime.Plugins.DefaultPluginManager.ResolvePlugins(String matchPath, String contentRootPath, IAssemblyResolver assemblyResolver)

   at Sitecore.Framework.Runtime.Plugins.DefaultPluginManager.ResolveBuildTimePlugins(IAssemblyResolver defaultAssemblyResolver, String contentRootPath)

   at Sitecore.Framework.Runtime.Plugins.DefaultPluginManager.ResolvePlugins(IAssemblyResolver defaultAssemblyResolver, IAssemblyResolver runtimeAssemblyResolver, ISitecorePluginFilterStrategy filterStrategy, ISitecorePluginSortStrategy sortStrategy, ISitecoreHostingEnvironment host)

   at Sitecore.Framework.Runtime.Plugins.DefaultPluginManager..ctor(ISitecoreHostingEnvironment host, IAssemblyResolverFactory assemblyResolverFactory, ISitecorePluginFilterStrategy filterStrategy, ISitecorePluginSortStrategy sortStrategy, IOptions`1 options)

   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)

   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)

   at Sitecore.Framework.Runtime.Licensing.ConsumptionTracking.Initialize(License license, ServiceProvider services)

   at Sitecore.Framework.Runtime.Commands.SitecoreHostCommand.OnExecuteAsync(CommandLineApplication app)

   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.Conventions.ExecuteMethodConvention.InvokeAsync(MethodInfo method, Object instance, Object[] arguments)

   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.Conventions.ExecuteMethodConvention.OnExecute(ConventionContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.Conventions.ExecuteMethodConvention.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<Apply>b__0>d.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.ExecuteAsync(String[] args, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.ExecuteAsync[TApp](CommandLineContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Sitecore.Program.<Main>(String[] args)```

I'm running the docker-examples from Sitecore git, which can he found here: https://github.com/Sitecore/docker-examples

This is where I'm getting the error at.
````

Comment: Which compose files are you running?

Comment: The docker-compose-overide.yml from the Github

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by a bug in Docker: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/12701. The fix is to roll back to 4.6 until Docker releases version 4.9